# ¿Cómo habría evolucionado el número de hablantes de español entre los siglos XI y XXI?

Tags: historia, español-medieval, español-medio

Las [estimaciones demográficas para el territorio que actualmente ocupa España](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimates_of_historical_world_population#World_Population_Estimates,_20_Countries_and_Regional_Totals,_0%E2%80%932000_AD_(in_thousands)) que da Wikipedia son:

siglo XI: 4 millones

siglo XVI: 6,8 millones

siglo XVII: 8,24 millones

siglo XVIII: 8,77 millones

1820: 12,203 millones

1870: 16,201 millones

1900: 20,263 millones

1950: 27,868 millones

Para Latinoamérica (incluyendo Brasil) se tiene:

1600: 8,2 millones

1700: 12,5 millones

1820: 21,22 millones

1870: 39,97 millones

1900: 80,52 millones

1950: 165,84 millones

Mis preguntas son:

1. Creo que estimando el porcentaje de personas que dentro del territorio español actual y dentro de América Latina hablaba español (bajo hasta 1800! y descontando la parte de Brasil) se podría dar una estimación razonable. No busco un número concreto, sólo una estimación informal.
2. Hacia qué año el número de hablantes de español fuera de España excedió a los que había en España (conjeturo que hacia 1840-50)

Answer (score 1):

¿Cómo habría evolucionado el número de hablantes de español entre los siglos XI y XXI?

---

2. - ¿*Hacia qué año el número de hablantes de español, fuera de España, excedió a los que había en España*?. (conjeturo que hacia 1840-50)

Aproximadamente casi estas en lo cierto cuando te refieres a la fecha en la que el número de hablantes en América excedió a los hablantes de la Península Ibérica, más concretamente fue en la década de 1860 y 1870, cuando los hablantes del Español de América, superaron por primera vez, no solo al Español de España, sino al conjunto o computo total de hablantes de Español de todos los demás territorios no Americanos, donde igualmente se hablaba Español. (Oceanía y África).

---

1. - *Creo que estimando el porcentaje de personas que dentro del territorio español actual y dentro de América Latina hablaba español (bajo hasta 1800! y descontando la parte de Brasil) se podría dar una estimación razonable. No busco un número concreto, sólo una estimación informal*.

En términos relativos, del S.XVIII al XIX la población mundial paso de unos 680 millones de habitantes, a 955 millones, aproximadamente. Sin embargo, cuando se hace un estudio del "Español" como lengua hablada en América, las consideraciones y cálculos exponenciales que se realizan para la población no sirven para los hablantes que viven en esas zonas, ya que sin ir más lejos hay que tener en cuenta, entre otros aspectos, como al terminar el S.XVIII, solo uno de cada tres iberoamericanos hablaba Español, así, si estimamos que la población aproximada en esa época es de unos doce o trece millones de habitantes, solo cuatro millones y algo más de esos doce o trece, serían los que hablarían realmente Español.

El número de hablantes del Español en América comenzará a crecer a partir precisamente del S. XIX, con las guerras de independencia de los países que conformaban el antiguo Imperio Español. La razón de ello son las nuevas legislaciones sobre lingüística que van apareciendo en esos países que hacen del Español la lengua oficial de las nuevas demarcaciones, ya que hasta entonces, y esto es poco conocido, la adopción del Español en los nuevos territorios había sido más bien pobre, ya que tanto la Ley de la época como la Iglesia sostenían la conveniencia de predicar y enseñar a los nativos en sus propias lenguas, impidiendo con este proceder la expansión del Español. Los Españoles han sido criticados por muchas razones, con o sin ella, sin embargo, en este caso, España constituyó y constituye el único ejemplo en el que lenguas como el "quechua o el nahua", lenguas dominadas, salen más fortalecidas al concluir el "período Español" que durante etapas posteriores.

Estimación razonable;

- A principios del S XIX en Iberoamérica, de los casi veinte millones que había aproximadamente en esa fecha, solo unos cinco millones eran hablantes de Español.
- Después de las diferentes proclamaciones de Independencia y de la declaración del Español como lengua oficial de esos territorios, el número de hablantes en toda Iberoamérica aumento exponencialmente, creciendo y superando los veinte millones para 1870, convirtiéndose y superando a España en número de personas que hablaban Español.